# Unity and Facebook 6.0 : Resolving host timed out: integrated-plugin-canvas-rsrc.fbsbx.com

Tags: ios, facebook, macos, unity-game-engine

When I tried to use the Facebook SDK 6.0 for Unity, sometimes it works, and sometimes I have this error message :

Resolving host timed out: integrated-plugin-canvas-rsrc.fbsbx.com
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
FbDebug:Error(String)
c__IteratorA:MoveNext() (at Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs:398)

I have the same error when I tried to build my project for MAC.

It works on mobile perfectly.

Any idea ?

(I already change the UNITY 4_5 to UNITY 4_6 in the post processor file .. I'm using the 4_6)

Thanks a lot !

Best regards,

AB

Answer (score 0):

I brute-forced it, here is my modified `LoadFacebookClass` method from `FB.cs` file, it will try multiple times, usually it takes 5 to 15 tries to download the .dll.

```
public static IEnumerator LoadFacebookClass(string className, LoadedDllCallback callback)
    {
        int tryAgainForFewTimes = 20; //--Changed--
        while(tryAgainForFewTimes-- > 0) //--Changed--
        {
            var url = string.Format(IntegratedPluginCanvasLocation.DllUrl, className);
            var www = new WWW(url);
            FbDebug.Log("loading dll: " + url);
            yield return www;

            if (www.error != null)
            {
                FbDebug.Error(www.error);
                print("retry: " + tryAgainForFewTimes); //--Changed--
                continue;    //--Changed--
            }
            tryAgainForFewTimes = 0; //--Changed--

#if !UNITY_WINRT
#if UNITY_4_5 || UNITY_4_6 || UNITY_5_0
            var authTokenWww = new WWW(IntegratedPluginCanvasLocation.KeyUrl);
            yield return authTokenWww;
            if (authTokenWww.error != null)
            {
                FbDebug.Error("Cannot load from " + IntegratedPluginCanvasLocation.KeyUrl + ": " + authTokenWww.error);
                authTokenWww.Dispose();
                yield break;
            }
            var assembly = Security.LoadAndVerifyAssembly(www.bytes, authTokenWww.text);
#else
            var assembly = Security.LoadAndVerifyAssembly(www.bytes);
#endif
            if (assembly == null)
            {
                FbDebug.Error("Could not securely load assembly from " + url);
                www.Dispose();
                yield break;
            }

            var facebookClass = assembly.GetType(facebookNamespace + className);
            if (facebookClass == null)
            {
                FbDebug.Error(className + " not found in assembly!");
                www.Dispose();
                yield break;
            }

            // load the Facebook component into the gameobject
            // using the "as" cast so it'll null if it fails to cast, instead of exception
            var fb = typeof(FBComponentFactory)
                    .GetMethod("GetComponent")
                    .MakeGenericMethod(facebookClass)
                    .Invoke(null, new object[] { IfNotExist.AddNew }) as IFacebook;

            if (fb == null)
            {
                FbDebug.Error(className + " couldn't be created.");
                www.Dispose();
                yield break;
            }

            callback(fb);
#endif
            www.Dispose();
        } //--Changed--
    }
```